# Right-continuity at zero of a cumulative distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Show that the function

$$
F(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/k, \infty)}(x) \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
is right-continuous at $0$.

Clearly, $F(0)=0$. Now, let $(x_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be such that $x_m \downarrow 0$. One then needs to show that
$$
\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} | F(x_m) - F(x)| = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} F(x_m) = \lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/k, \infty)}(x_m) = \lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty}  \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{ k = 1 }^{ n } \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/k, \infty)}(x_m) \right) =0.
$$
It then seems evident, that exchanging the order of limits should yield the result. But is this possible? Here is one attempt. Consider the measure space $( \mathbb{N}, \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure, i.e., for $A \in \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$
$$
\mu(A)=
\begin{cases}
|A|, \quad \text{if} \quad |A|<\infty, \\
\infty, \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
We can then rewrite
$$
\lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/k, \infty)}(x_m) = \lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_{ \{ k \} } \frac{1}{2^s} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/s, \infty)}(x_m) \mu (d s ) = \lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty } \int_{ \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^s} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/s, \infty)}(x_m) \mu (ds).
$$
Moroever,
$$
\frac{1}{2^s} \cdot {\Large 1}_{[1/s, \infty]}(x_m) \leq \frac{1}{2^s} \quad \forall s \in \mathbb{N},
$$
with
$$
\int_{ \mathbb{N} } \frac{1}{2^s} \mu ( d s ) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k} = 1 < \infty,
$$
and the dominated convergence theorem then implies that $\lim_{ m \rightarrow \infty }$ can be taken inside the integral, which yields the desired result.

---

Here are some questions:

1. Is the approach above correct?
2. Are there simpler approaches?

Comment: Yes I do like this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely correct. I think the argumentation is pretty much as simple as it gets. You somehow have to find an argument for interchanging limits. Dominated convergence is the obvious and easy one.